# show that $a^T\lambda + a_0$ is equivalen to $\lambda^T(1/2(ea^T + ae^T) + a_0 E)\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, convex-optimization

Affine function $f(\lambda)=a^T\lambda + a_0$ where $a, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}^n,a_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ is in a unit simplex,i.e., $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda =1, \lambda\in \mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Show that this affine function is equivalen to 
$\lambda^T(\tfrac{1}{2}(ea^T + ae^T) + a_0 E)\lambda$, where $E= ee^T$ and $e$ is a vector with components all valued $1$.

My intutition is as follows.

Exploit the fact that $\lambda^Te=e^T\lambda =1 $ by left multiplying $\lambda^Te$ to the function $f(\lambda)$, and then just right multipying $e^T\lambda$ to the single term $\lambda^Tea_0$.

But the result is

$\lambda^T(ea^T  + a_0 E)\lambda$...
what is wrong with my deduction ?

Answer (score 1):

Just go in the reverse direction.
$$\lambda^T(\tfrac{1}{2}(ea^T + ae^T) + a_0 E)\lambda = \tfrac{1}{2} \lambda^Tea^T\lambda + \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^Tae^T\lambda + a_0\lambda^Tee^T\lambda$$
The first term:
$$\lambda^Tea^T\lambda=(\lambda^Te)(a^T\lambda)=a^T\lambda$$
The second term:
$$\lambda^Tae^T\lambda=(\lambda^Ta)(e^T\lambda)=\lambda^Ta = a^T\lambda$$
The third term:
 is the transpose of the first, so it's the same. And finally,
$$\lambda^Tee^T\lambda=(\lambda^Te)(e^T\lambda)=1.$$
So the expression equals
$$\tfrac{1}{2} a^T \lambda + \tfrac{1}{2} \lambda^Ta + a_0 = a^T\lambda + a_0$$
To finish your approach, just note that for a real scalar $b$, $b=\tfrac{1}{2}(b+b^T)$. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
\lambda^T(ea^T+a_0E)\lambda 
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^T(ea^T+a_0E)\lambda + \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\lambda^T(ea^T+a_0E)\lambda\right))^T \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^T(ea^T+a_0E)\lambda + \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^T(a^Te+a_0E)\lambda \\
 &= \tfrac{1}{2}\lambda^T(ea^T+ae^T+2a_0E)\lambda =
 \lambda^T(\tfrac{1}{2}(ea^T+ae^T)+a_0E)\lambda.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you Michale. You answer is complete. But I have a further question: what is the usage of the fact $b = \frac{1}{2} (b+b^T)$ where $b$ is a scalar? I mean if this hold, why we need the R.H.S expression instead of the L.H.S which is more concise ?

Comment: I assume that what is wanted is the quadratic coefficient matrix---that is, $\tfrac{1}{2}(ea^T+ae^T)+a_0ee^T$---and generally the symmetric form is preferred. This is also the Hessian of the quadratic form, and that Hessian is always symmetric. My guess is that in some other analysis, it helps to treat this problem as a convex QP instead of an LP. Arguably, the RHS is more "compact". After all, it only has $n(n+1)/2$ unique values, due to symmetry, whereas the LHS has $n^2$.